# Disable apple Cmd key on Centos/Gnome in VM

Tags: macos, vmware, gnome, centos-7

I've installed Centos 7 in a VMware VM under MacOs.  When I press the Command/Apple key, Centos arranges all of the windows and displays a search box.

This is annoying because I often use CMD-Tab to switch between applications on the mac.

How can I disable (or reassign the key) in Centos? I'd like Centos to ignore completely the CMD/Apple key.

[image: Centos with Search Box]

Comment: How did you resolve this

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Gnome Wayland, switch to XOrg and it will start working normally.